# How to add text in between html tags

Tags: php, html, string, insert, tags

I want to add a string in between html tags in php. I'm using php's dom document class and you can only add strings inside html. Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish

```
<tag>example</tag><another>sometext</another>
```

I want to add a string in-between these two tags so it should look like

```
 <tag>example</tag>STRING<another>sometext</another>
```

I want to be able to seperate these tags so I can use the explode function to split every tag in the html page to an array then traverse them for later use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a textnode without being or having a tag.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$tag = $doc->createElement('tag');
$doc->appendChild($tag);
$tag->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('example'));

$node = $doc->createTextNode('STRING');
$doc->appendChild($node);

$another = $doc->createElement('another');
$doc->appendChild($another);
$another->appendChild($doc->createTextNode('sometext'));

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

will give

```
<tag>example</tag>STRING<another>sometext</another>
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to connect php and html.
Exemple:

```
<?php echo "<tag>example</tag>.'STRING'.<another>sometext</another> " ?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).